# No wifi with ubuntu/no ethernet with windows

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, ethernet

I realize that due to the nature of my question I might not get answers here, but no harm in trying right?

My dilemma is that I recently setup ubuntu 15.10 to dual boot with windows 10. However ever since I installed it, I cannot get my ethernet connection on windows 10 to work, but wifi works fine. Ironically, the ethernet connection works but not wifi. 
Considering this all happened after I installed ubuntu next to windows, Im guessing there is something both oses cant share.
Ive already read up numerous posts, but nothing particular seems to have worked; for either problem.
What data do you guys require to help me with my problem?
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: can you [edit] your post with the output of  this command `lspci` and the command `ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

I've found that since Linux (straight forms without 'non-free' code blobs) usually installs ok on Ethernet ports, as most of the firmware is available, but the wifi is usually missing.  Although I'm not nearly a Windows guru, I have found that it behaves eradicly when it's not a power on boot or a re-boot, as windows appears to assume things 'not in evidence'.  This seems especially true with Windows 10.

Search for threads for your wifi in the proper Linux group identifying you hardware chipset.  This should guide you through that part.  Maybe you need to do a power off reset for Windows to reset the Ethernet ports. Of course most of this is person assumptions.

You can find your device ID's and info with the lspci, as com ports are on a pci controller, use the v option initially and if you want more info, make if '-vv' as:

```
lspci -v[v]
```